# Why isn't Windows 8 detecting my Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon-d3100, windows, usb

I have a Windows 8 PC and my Nikon D3100 isn't showing up on it. It says USB device not recognized. I have updated the USB drivers, but no joy. Sadly, i don't have the disc that came with it.

Comment: check this link, it may help you:  https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18028/~/microsoft-windows-8-compatibility-announcement

Comment: I did install this software but it doesn't detect my camera. Neither does Windows. I have tried all the ports, but still no go.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson - which software did you install?

Comment: its called ViewNX 2

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but anyway: is your camera is detected ok on any other PC / different OS?

Comment: ViewNX is just the viewer software, not a driver.  What USB mode is the camera in (and set it to mass transfer/MTP if you're still having trouble?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the disk that came with it - it SHOULD be recognised as a mass storage device or a camera by the OS.

Check list:

- Plug camera into computer, turn on camera
- Does your computer do ANYTHING? any sounds, movement, anything show up in My Computer?
- check under "My Devices", nothing there?
- try a different cable
- Try the camera on a different computer
- do OTHER usb devices work in the same port ok?
- look in Device Manager (wherever that is in 8) is there a device with a ! next to it?

if the camera is not detected by ANY computer with a known working cable, take it back to the shop.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys.. i figures it was my computer!