# Windows 10 doesn't recognize Nikon D3100 on usb connect

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, usb, windows-10

It seems that my Windows 10 doesn't recognize my Nikon D3100 camera when i plug it in on usb and turn it on.

It does show something like the device is turned on (you know the sound when usb device is connected to pc) but that's all that it shows. I know that everything else is working as i connected it on other pc without problems, it just my windows doesn't recognize it.

When i go to Computer Management i see two things that are kinda registered with Windows but with exclamation mark on them

```
CIF Single Chip

Unknown USB Device(Device Decriptor Request Failed)
```

I think the second id camera maybe because that one disappear when i turn off camera, but anyway i tried to reinstall remove update and search for driver online but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do come back and ask about some *photography* questions :)

Comment: Please take a look at the following questions and ensure your issue is not the same: [Why isn't Windows 8 detecting my Nikon D3100?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/why-isnt-windows-8-detecting-my-nikon-d3100) and [Why can't I see photos from my Nikon camera after upgrading to Windows 10?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/66009/why-cant-i-see-photos-from-my-nikon-camera-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)

Comment: I did checked those threads but no luck, i tried to install codec pack and also ViewNX software and not working.

Comment: Did you try a USB card reader?

Comment: Delete the non-working devices in Computer Management. Disconnect everything. Power everything off. Restart computer. Try to connect camera to computer again.